# Can I create settlements without workstations?

Tags: fallout-4

I have at least one settlement without a workshop. How do I make one without being able to build it? I have cleared the settlement, so no there are no monsters.

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity, please let me know if it has retained the original meaning.

Comment: A settlement is defined in the game as having a Workshop. Without one, it is just a place to visit, not an area to build. Unless you have mods that can add Workshops where you please, then this case stands.

Comment: Can you specify which location this is? @Kaizerwolf is correct, if there is not a [Workshop](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Workshop) at the given location, it is **not** a settlement. There are some places that have a bunch of workbenches and workstations at them, but aren't settlements because they do not have a workshop. I recall Fort Hagen being an example of this case.

Answer (score 5):

A settlement is defined in the game as having a Workshop. The [Fallout 4 Wikia Page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_settlements) details the information on settlements and settlement building, as well as a list of settlements that can be used. The list is as follows:

### Vanilla Fallout 4

- Abernathy Farms
- Boston Airport
- Bunker Hill
- The Castle
- Coastal Cottage
- County Crossing
- Covenant
- Croup Manor
- Egret Tours Marina
- Finch Farm
- Graygarden
- Greentop Nursery
- Hangman's Alley
- Home Plate
- Jamaica Plain
- Kingsport Lighthouse
- Murkwater Construction Site
- Nordhagen Beach
- Oberland Station
- Outpost Zimonja
- Red Rocket Truck Stop
- Sanctuary Hills
- The Slog
- Somerville Place
- Spectacle Island
- Starlight Drive-In
- Sunshine Tidings Co-op
- Taffington Boathouse
- Tenpines Bluff
- Warwick Homestead

### Automatron

- The Mechanist's Lair

### Far Harbor

- Longfellow's Cabin
- Dalton Farm
- National Park Visitor's Center
- Echo Lake Lumber

### VaultTec DLC

- Vault 88

As of writing this on August 9th 2016, these are all the available settlement workshops. It is possible that NukaWorld will add settlements as well.